# Restore stock lubuntu-rc.xml

Tags: lubuntu

I'm on Lubuntu 14.10. I appear to have messed up my `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`file - no shortcuts work. How can I redownload the default one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the old configuration out of the way and log in again. Defaults should be restored.

```
mv ~/.config/openbox{,-backup}
```

Comment: The system says: `mv: invalid option -- 'a'`